# My mousedown function in canvas isn't redrawing the background when it is being called

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

The link to my CodePen - http://codepen.io/PartTimeCoder/pen/oxapjq?editors=0010

My JavaScript is below, the problem has to do something with the .addEventListener near the bottom of the code:

```
var randomPosX = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * width * 0.975);
}

var randomPosY = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * height * 0.975);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

var button = document.getElementById("button");

var height = window.innerHeight
var width = window.innerWidth

canvas.width = width
canvas.height = height

var mouse = {};

ctx.font = "35px Quicksand";
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Try and Click the White Square", width / 2, height / 2);

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mousePos, false);
canvas.addEventListener('touch', mousePos, false);

function mousePos(e) {
    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
}

var xPos = randomPosX();
var yPos = randomPosY();

var rectWidth = 10;
var rectHeight = 10;

ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
ctx.rect(xPos, yPos, rectWidth, rectHeight);
ctx.stroke();

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    if (mouse.x > xPos && mouse.x < xPos + rectWidth && mouse.y > yPos && mouse.y < yPos + rectHeight) {
        xPos = randomPosX();
        yPos = randomPosY();

        rectWidth -= 1;
        rectHeight -= 1;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

        ctx.font = "35px Quicksand";
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillText("Try and Click the White Square", width / 2, height / 2);

        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
        ctx.rect(xPos, yPos, rectWidth, rectHeight);
        ctx.stroke();

        console.log("Work");

        if (rectWidth == 1 && rectHeight == 1) {
            alert("You won! Congratulations!");
        }
    }
});

if (rectWidth == 1 && rectHeight == 1) {
    console.log("You won! Congratulations!");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Thanks in advance! All help is appreciated!

Comment: In canvas.onmousedown, you're not calling any code to redraw any background -- you've got clear, text, white-rect so all you're getting is the canvas's CSS background-color.

Comment: I tried fillRect, it still didn't work for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var randomPosX = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * width * 0.975);
};

var randomPosY = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * height * 0.975);
};

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var button = document.getElementById("button");

var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var mouse = {};



canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mousePos, false);
canvas.addEventListener('touch', mousePos, false);

function mousePos(e) {
    mouse.x = e.pageX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY;
}

var xPos = randomPosX();
var yPos = randomPosY();

var rectWidth = 10;
var rectHeight = 10;



function draw(){
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, width, height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#3498db";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.font = "35px Quicksand";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";

    ctx.fillText("Try and Click the White Square", width / 2, height / 2);
    ctx.save();

}


function drawSquare(){

    rectWidth -= 1;
    rectHeight -= 1;

    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.rect(xPos, yPos, rectWidth, rectHeight);
    ctx.stroke();

}

draw();
drawSquare();

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {

    if (mouse.x > xPos && mouse.x < xPos + rectWidth && mouse.y > yPos && mouse.y < yPos + rectHeight) {
        xPos = randomPosX();
        yPos = randomPosY();


        draw();
        drawSquare();


        if (rectWidth == 1 && rectHeight == 1) {
            alert("You won! Congratulations!");
        }


    }

});
```